# How to access radio environment information from an Android miui phone

Tags: android, cellinfogsm

I'm trying to get some radio environment information from an android phone. This means not only info on the serving cell but also on the neighbors, their radio conditions, timing advance, channels, etc.

From java api only few information can be retrieved; I believe one should be able to get that info if he can access the vendor ril even though I'm not sure about what is the info available. I was wondering if it would be possible to modify and recompile the vendor RIL from MIUI and load it on a compatible phone.

Anybody with some experience in such manipulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RIL is basically an interface layer between your Android framework and Modem.It is not something where you can find information regarding cells, neighbouring cells etc.

All information is requested by Android Framework via APIs. The RIL then sends the appropriate AT Command to the Modem for the requested info. The response from the Modem is parsed by RIL and information provided back to Android framework by the same API.

For information regarding cells/ neighboring cells, you can use the following dial code:

1. Dial * #*#4636# *# * (Please remove spaces when dialing), a menu will pop up.
2. Tap on phone information
3. Information regarding network registration, Cell ID, neighbouring Cell ID and more can be seen on the screen.

You can refer to the video in the following link: https://youtu.be/7pjo5sOhn7U